# How to resolve Can't set headers after they are sent, in express framework NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Building first `express` application, bear with me...

The application has a `user` `login`, `authenticating` with an API.

Enter some information and `post` an API call, then send a text message based on data entered and the API data returned.

Upon the first `login` got no error, application runs successfully, text sent, user redirected back to login screen.

Upon the second `login`, got the following errors on the `login/auth` function.

1. `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent`.
2. `TypeError: req.next is not a function`

Don't see duplicate call backs, but maybe missing something, and do not have `next` defined in my code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXQbQ.jpg)

Here is the code where it seems to be failing...

```
//login page -  post
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req,res) {
    //console.log(req.body);    
    username = req.body.username
    password = req.body.password


    //Login function / Routing to rbhGetMRN
    var authEHR = function(){
        console.log('AuthEHR:');
        var json = buildJSON('GetUserAuthentication', Appname, username, '', token, password);

        unityAction(json, function(body) {
            console.log('Output from GetUserAuthentication: ');
            //console.log(body);
            usrData = JSON.parse(body)
            var valid_user = usrData[0]['getuserauthenticationinfo'][0]['ValidUser'];

            if (valid_user == 'YES') {
                res.render('rbhGetMRN');
                res.end();
                console.log('Login Success');

            }

            else {
                //console.log('EHR user is invalid: ' + usrData[0]['getuserauthenticationinfo'][0]['ErrorMessage']);
                console.log('Login Failure');
                res.render('rbhLogin');
                res.end();
                emitter.emit('CleanUp');
            }

        });


    };
});
```

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You don't need to end your response when using `res.render`.

Comment: thanks i will check that.

Comment: `console.log('else statement');  
            else {` this is invalid syntax.

Comment: thanks @YuryTarabanko i was trying to put some checks in there to validate what was failing.

Comment: did you manage to solve the problem? if not, would you post more code since it's not very clear what is happening, esp how `authEHR` is called?

Comment: I did not, the var 'authEHR' is part of an emitter called here and in a function to get an API token.